# Write a file for each element of an array in Node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, foreach, writefile

I am completely new to Node.js. This might be really easy, but I cannot make it work. I want to create an empty file called "employee.txt" for each element in an array. I am using writeFileSync and the forEach loop, but it creates only 1 file with the last element in it.

Below is my code. Thanks a lot!

```
const fs = require ('fs')
let employees = ['Daniel', 'Sarah', 'Julia', 'Rob', 'Alex']

employees.forEach (employee => {
  fs.writeFileSync('employee.txt',employee+"\r\n")
})
```

Comment: you are overwriting the same file

Comment: isn't this an OS issue? you can't have multiple files named the same in the same directory

Comment: Ahhh, I see! And how can I create different files with different names? Do I need to use a for loop? Thank you both very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try renaming the file to something different like

```
const fs = require ('fs');
let employees = ['Daniel', 'Sarah', 'Julia', 'Rob', 'Alex'];

employees.forEach (employee => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${employee}.txt`, employee+"\r\n")
});
```

that way every file will be named with the employee name. if you're gonna have multiple employees with the same name maybe use index too

```
employees.forEach ((employee, index) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${employee} ${index}.txt`, employee+"\r\n")
});
```